# translation or translating?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

In the below example what we should use with **while** to represent the target image moving while similarity estimate in each step.

> To find the ideal alignment, the method required an X function
>   represent the similarity of the overlap area between a fixed and
>   target images while the target image [is] **translating**.

OR

> To find the ideal alignment, the method required an X function
>   represent the similarity of the overlap area between a fixed and
>   target images while the target image **translation**.

Why do you decide to use it?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, nagdawi, both of these sentences are incorrect, because **while** must be followed by a clause containint a verb. for example "..while the target image is translating**. it would be helpful if you could provide some more context, by expaining in more detail what the while clause is supposed to mean. There are other mistakes in the sentence too, but let's stick to the while clause first.

Comment: clarify the question more

Answer (score 1):

**translating** is an active participle, which works like an adjective and requires a **be-verb** to specify when an activity took/takes place.

> He **was** translating the letter yesterday 
>   He **is** translating the letter now
>   He **will be** translating the letter tomorrow

**translation** is a noun that describes the activity, or the product of an activity, but cannot be used with a **be-verb** to specify when it took place.

> He is good at translation. - *activity*
>   This is a translation of the letter - *product*.

For some verbs, it is a bit confusing because the -ing form can be used as both active participle and noun (but only as an activity, not a product):

> The boy is running
>   I like running

In your sentence, the while-clause indicates that you want to talk about an activity that is taking place, so you need an active participle (the **-ing** form). Here is the sentence, with a couple of other errors fixed.

> To find the ideal alignment, the method **requires** an X function **to** represent the similarity of the overlap area between the fixed and target images while the target image is translating.

**required** (simple past) is for talking about something that was true in the past, but is no longer true. **requires** (present simple) is the correct verb form to use about a situation that was, is and always will be true.

**requires** is the main verb in the middle clause and you can't have two main verbs in the same clause, so represent needs an infinitive marker.

Here is a simpler example, where need and light are both verbs:

> You need a match light a fire - *wrong*
>   You need a match **to** light a fire - *right*

Translating can be used about movement, but this usage is very techincal. The main meaning is converting from one language to another. It might be clearer to say **moving** rather than **translating**.

Comment: They also might have it confused with "transiting".